# Parallax effect not working to the background color when scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I am having a problem with parallax effect. I have a image and at the back side of this image I have a color. Below is the html that I have.

```
<div class="rectangle background-medium-blue header-stage-medium-blue-rectangle"></div>


<div class="image">
    <img class="img" src="stage-allviewports-4x3.jpg" width="1450" height="1089" />
</div>
```

My problem is when I start scrolling this blue rectangle moves to top and doesnot come down.

```
var parallax= document.querySelector(".header-stage-medium-blue-rectangle");

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {

    var scrolledHeight= window.pageYOffset;

    parallax.style.top=  (scrolledHeight * 0.2) + "px";
});
```

### css

```
.header-stage-medium-blue-rectangle {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    right: 0px;
    top: 302px;
}
```

Comment: Please, post the CSS.

Comment: @Passele I have added css